# freeRadius, dynamic clients with 32 bit integer mask

Tags: freeradius

I'll trying to use free radius in public web(internet), is it possible to use dynamic clients with wide ip range without server restarting?

from freeradius dynamic clients example file: #  You MUST specify a netmask!#  IPv4 /32 or IPv6 /128 are NOT allowed!

solution with client 0.0.0.0/0 is not working for me - i need to distinguish clients

also i'm using SQL for NAS list

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You can use Packet-Src-IP-Address to distinguish between packets originating from different clients, and use an SQL query to retrieve additional info e.g.:

```
authorize {
    update request {
        Tmp-String-0 := "%{sql:SELECT `info` FROM `client_table` WHERE ip = '%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}'"
    }
}
```

Comment: if a client not in the freeradius client list(as i can see in debug mode), server skips connection and so authorize can't be triggered

Comment: The wildcard client syntax should work, you'd need to post the exact client definition you're using.